# iOS NSRegularExpression how to find the first matching "TAIL" of pattern like: HEAD(.*)TAIL

Tags: ios, regex

For example:

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"hello: (.*)ABC" options:0 error:NULL];
NSString *str = @"hello: bobABC123ABC";
NSTextCheckingResult *match = [regex firstMatchInString:str options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [str length])];
NSLog(@"macthing part is %@", [str substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:0]]);
```

The result of matching is "bobABC123ABC", so the matching of "ABC" in NSRegularExpression is finding the last "ABC" in the string instead of first.
I want the matching to be "bob",any one know how to achieve this?

Comment: You want to match only the _bob_ or _bobABC_?

Comment: match the first "ABC" instead of last "ABC"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make you regular expression non-greedy.  Say:

```
@"hello: (.*?)ABC"
            ^
            |==> note this
```

instead of

```
@"hello: (.*)ABC"
```

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> *?  Match 0 or more times. Match as few times as possible.